# decode error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\xe8' in python

Tags: python

I have a unicode string thus I wanna check if the character is continuation bit or starting bit  so as tot count the number of unicode character through simple programme as

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



def arg(str):

  i = 0
  j = 0
  print i

  for test in str:
    print test
    value = int(test,16)
    if (value & 0xc0) != 0x80:
        j=j+1
        print "hello"

  print j
  #return j






def main():
    print "inside main"

    new = "象形字"

    charlen = len(new)
    print charlen
    tes = new.decode('utf-8')

    declen = len(tes)
    print declen


    data = tes.encode('utf-8')


    # print self_len

    enclen = len(data)
    print enclen

    print data

    arg(data)







if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

running the code gives the error as

```
象形字[Decode error - output not utf-8]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/laxmi518/Documents/laxmi/code/C/python-c/python_unicode.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/laxmi518/Documents/laxmi/code/C/python-c/python_unicode.py", line 52, in main
    arg(data)
  File "/Users/laxmi518/Documents/laxmi/code/C/python-c/python_unicode.py", line 16, in arg
    value = int(test,16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\xe8'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 bytes are *not hex strings*. They are just bytes, and Python will display bytes outside the ASCII printable range by using the literal escape syntax. This is *just* a debugging display notation.

Use the [`ord()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) to get the numerical value of a byte:

```
value = ord(test)
```

With that change, running your script in a terminal on Mac OS X (configured for UTF-8) outputs:

```
inside main
9
3
9
象形字
0
?
hello
?
?
?
hello
?
?
?
hello
?
?
3
```

The question marks are generated by the terminal; printing a single byte from a UTF-8 bytestream means you are printing *incomplete* UTF-8 code units, so the terminal doesn't know what to do with those and produces a placeholder character instead.

Instead of printing `test` directly, print the output of the `repr()` function:

```
print repr(test)
```

to get a `\xhh` hex notation for those bytes instead:

```
inside main
9
3
9
象形字
0
'\xe8'
hello
'\xb1'
'\xa1'
'\xe5'
hello
'\xbd'
'\xa2'
'\xe5'
hello
'\xad'
'\x97'
3
```

Comment: still gives the error using  ord [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Comment: @user3545251: something else gives that output, that's not a Python error. What kid of console or terminal are you running this in?

Comment: @user3545251: you are printing incomplete UTF-8 code units (single bytes), so it depends on your console how those are handled.

Comment: i am using mac machine

Comment: @user3545251: but not the terminal, at least not the same setting as I am using. Are you using an IDE or text editor? IDLE, or PyCharm or SublimeText?